# Python (2.7): Simple version checker

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, urllib

A preface: I'm a beginner at Python. I've tried guides for learning but I am awful at learning like that, so I'm trying to make a super simple update checker to get started that I slowly build upon. I've grabbed some code I found on here and modified it a bit, and alas, it doesn't work. It reads the local and external .txt files and prints their output (just to check that it's reading them correctly). It then fails at the if/elif/elif/else statement thing in some way, so some help there would be great!

It's currently telling me "NameError: global name 'i' is not defined" however I've gone through several different errors at this point and am really just looking for a solution, and from there I can work backwards. Thanks!

```
import Tkinter
import urllib
import time

print "test"

#previously self within the brackets
def updateCheck():
    update = False

    updateWindow = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    updateWindow.title(string="Update Checker")
    updateWindow.resizable(False, False)

    #gets local version (file currently says "1.0")
    localSource = open('version.txt', 'r')
    localContents = localSource.read()
    print "local version = " + localContents

    #gets server version (file currently says "1.1")
    serverSource = urllib.urlopen("http://raw.github.com/SamHH/ccr-version/master/version.txt")
    serverContents = serverSource.read()
    print "server version = " + serverContents

    #checks for updates by comparing the above two -- doesn't work
    if serverContents[i] > localContents[i]:
        dataLabel = Tkinter.Label(updateWindow,text="\n\nThere is an update available.\n\n")
        dataLabel.pack()
        #need a way of opening a .url file in the same folder here, if possible
    elif serverContents[i] < localContents[i]:
        dataLabel = Tkinter.Label(updateWindow,text="\n\nYour installation appears to be broken.\n\n")
        dataLabel.pack()
        #need a way of opening a .url file in the same folder here, if possible, again
    elif serverContents[i] == localContents[i]:
        versionLabel = Tkinter.Label(updateWindow,text="\n\nYou are already running the most up to date version.\n\n")
        versionLabel.pack()
        #need a way of opening a .exe file in the same folder this time, if possible
    else:
        versionLabel = Tkinter.Label(updateWindow,text="\n\nYour install is corrupted. Doh!\n\n")
        versionLabel.pack()

updateCheck()
```

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to achieve? What do `localContents` and `serverSource` contain, and how should the comparisons work?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The idea is that it'll read the local and external .txt files, and when the number (float) is greater on the server/external one then it will prompt the user, ideally loading a .url in the same directory, although that isn't as important as just getting the information across. From there it's mostly the same idea, if the reads are the same then say there's no new updates (and ideally run a .exe in the same directory), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if serverContents[i] > localContents[i]:
```

Notice that you never initialized i to a default value. It is looking up in your code to see if you had defined and set it outside the function (which you did not).

Put in a loop

```
for i in range(len(serverContents)):
```

You should also check that both lists are the same size or you will get an error when you try to index past the end.

Note that this assumes that the serverContents and localContents are both lists each of whose elements is a value to be compared. If the contents are text strings. then you will be looping over each character in the string. If that is what you want, you do not need to do it

```
f = '1.1a'
g = '1.1a'

f == g # shows True
f is g # shows False
```

This will mean that '1.1a' and '01.1a' will show different

However, this will allow for the case where version number is not totally numeric, which is a requirement if you use float(serverContents).

Comment: This is actually all that's needed - just to check whether the two files match up entirely or not. I'm testing if it works in its current form or not.

Comment: Aha, it works! A simple if/else statement on if they're entirely identical or not is all that I need. Next question: How do I get Python to open a file (e.g. a .exe) in the same directory, assuming that's possible?

Comment: @user208247 As you see below, Martijn opens a file. You also open a file. It depends what you want to do with it. However, if you want to run a .exe file then us subprocess.Popen() or subprocess.call() google for the python instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If both local and remove 'files' contain just a float, read one line from each and turn that into a `float()` so you can compare:

```
try:
    localSource = open('version.txt', 'r')
    localContents = float(localSource.readline())
except (IOError, ValueError):
    versionLabel = Tkinter.Label(updateWindow,text="\n\nYour install is corrupted. Doh!\n\n")
    versionLabel.pack()
    return

serverSource = urllib.urlopen("http://raw.github.com/SamHH/ccr-version/master/version.txt")
serverContents = float(serverSource.readline())
```

You then use the `localContents` and `serverContents` names to compare:

```
if serverContents > localContents:
    # etc.
```

Comment: I get the same error. "in updateCheck
    if serverContents[i] > localContents[i]:
NameError: global name 'i' is not defined"

Comment: @user208247: that's only natural, you don't *have* an `i` variable. You don't need it either; you have just *one* value.

Comment: @user208247 Note that this only works for versions such as 1.1 but fails for 1.1a and 1.1.1 While this is what you asked for, make sure that you only have floating point numeric version numbers in your file names.

Comment: @sabbahillel: I was keeping it simple because the OP claims that the values are floats. The problem is not just `1.1.1` but also `1.9` upgrading to `1.10`. The OP may need to research proper version parsing..

Comment: @Martijn good point. I hadm\n't thought of the multiple digit problem with a text entry. You are right that 10 would be < 9 in txt. However, in this particular case, I think that as long as the server has a different value from the local, the server version would be correct no matter what the version value happens to be.

Comment: Now that I think of it, if all versions are numeric use split to get the integers and then check each element of the list to see if they differ. That woulds allow for the first larger element of each version number to be picked up.

Comment: @sabbahillel: Personally, I'd reach for the [`pkg_resources` module](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#parsing-utilities) (part of setuptools) to do the version parsing for me.